# How to merge two Linked Lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I have a *singly-linked* list:

> x1 -> x2 -> … None

Where `x`s are elements of this list and are called nodes. Each node stores some data.

I have tried:

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self,value:int):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None 
  
  # here I write a second method like merge
  
  def merge(list1:Node, list2:Node) -> Node:
    head_first = list1
    while head_first.next:
      head_first = head_first.next
      head_first.next = list2
    return list1


n1=Node(1)
n2=Node(2)
  
n1.next=n2
```

I want to join two lists, but the state of the arguments should not change.

But it doesn't work. I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the sample input and expected output

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? So far you haven't actually showed your implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
def merge(list1:Node, list2:Node) -> Node:
    head = list1
    while head.next:
        head = head.next
    head.next = list2
    return list1
```

Answer (score -1):

Can the answer be like this.

```
 x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
 y = {'b': 10, 'c': 11}
 z = x.update(y)
 print(z)
```